# paging a dataview webpart in sharepoint designer isn't working well

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

In have enabled paging in dataview webpart.But i noticed when i click the next page and then click the image previous it doesn't go back to the previous item but goes back to the previous page that i was in.
When i look at the code see below i found they are using history.back()
javascript: history.back();
How can this be fixed.
Cheers

```
  <a href="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_d76e2f6d_1d2e_4654_8bd5_0a51535bf2af$ctl02','dvt_firstrow={1};dvt_startposition={}');">
                                Start</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript: history.back();"><img src="/_layouts/images/prev.gif" alt="Previous" border="0"></a>&nbsp;2
                             - 2&nbsp;<a href="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_d76e2f6d_1d2e_4654_8bd5_0a51535bf2af$ctl02','dvt_firstrow={3};dvt_startposition={Paged=TRUE&amp;p_FileLeafRef=HTCSensation%2ejpg&amp;p_ID=1}');"><img src="/_layouts/images/next.gif" alt="Next" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: I have enabled "paging" for a dataview webpart but the previous link isn't working.
I noticed  its using using history.back() but this doesn't send me back to the previous page but to the main root site.
How can i fix this.This is OOTB and it doesn't work :(
Any solutions....
Can anyone help!!!

Answer (score 4):

In the Ajax properties of the webpart, uncheck "enable asynchronous update" (the text may be slightly different, Im working with SP with Spanish language pack)